# SQL Retrieving an object from VARRAY in Oracle 11g Database

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a schema RTRD_W  built in an Oracle 11g database that contains a table rtrd_pri that has a column NOMNL which is has a type defined as **VARRAY(10) OF KPS_ADM.NUMBER_T** (an object defined as a type in the KPS_ADM schema).  I am trying to run a query to **retrieve the KPS_ADM.NUMBER_T object** inside the varray but I keep getting an error returned in my SQL syntax.  The function I built is posted below

```
CREATE or replace function RETRIEVEPRIREF RETURN KPS_ADM.NUMBER_T AS
REF1 KPS_ADM.NUMBER_T;
BEGIN
SELECT KPS_ADM.NUMBER_T INTO REF1 from table(NOMNL) WHERE (SELECT NOMNL FROM RTRD_W.rtrd_pri WHERE (syst_id like '%0516%'));
RETURN REF1;
END RETRIEVEPRIREF;
```

I know the query :`SELECT NOMNL FROM RTRD_W.rtrd_pri WHERE (syst_id like '%0516%')` works and does return a varray with a single KPS_ADM.NUMBER_T object inside it, but I can't seem to get the syntax right for searching inside the varray to retrieve the object.

Can anyone show the proper syntax to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- an object defined as a type in the KPS_ADM schema
CREATE TYPE number_t        AS OBJECT (object_value NUMBER);
CREATE TYPE varray_number_t AS VARRAY(10) OF number_t;

CREATE TABLE rtrd_pri
(
    column_one NUMBER
,   column_two varray_number_t
);

INSERT INTO rtrd_pri VALUES(1, (varray_number_t(number_t(11), number_t(22))));
INSERT INTO rtrd_pri VALUES(2, (varray_number_t(number_t(33), number_t(44))));

SELECT  column_one, OBJECT_VALUE AS column_two
FROM    rtrd_pri, TABLE(rtrd_pri.column_two)
;

COLUMN_ONE  COLUMN_TWO
1           11
1           22
2           33
2           44
```